# Easy Flash question - use ems for width?

Tags: flash

Can I use ems for the width tag when embedding a flash object?

I've done some googling and it looks like it's just pixels and percentages but I want to double check with the stack overflow community.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an 'em' is only meaningful in the context of a typographical font size (eg in 12pt font, an em is 12 points, or 12 pixels at 72dpi). Since a flash object embedded in an HTML page doesn't really have a point size, it's hard to know how big an em should be... See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)'s description of an em.

That said, you should still be able to specify the width tag in ems, and the width will be calculated *relative to the 'font-size' property of the element (or in some cases it's parent)*. I haven't tested this however, and it may vary between browsers.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative0) for relative units in CSS.